# property files - best practices

Tags: file, properties

I have a xyz.properties file.
This file contains properties like:

```
abc.errorcode.mkd-003.useraccount = MKD-003|123-3456-8967|FADS
```

where the name of the property is 'abc.errorcode.mkd-003.useraccount' and the same name is mapped to different values, so instead of creating 3 different property files like :

```
abc.errorcode.mkd-003.useraccount = MKD-003
abc.errorcode.mkd-003.useraccount = 123-3456-8967
abc.errorcode.mkd-003.useraccount = FADS
```

I've merged them into 1 file and separated using pipelines. In my code I use string.split and collect every value in an array.

So, what is the best way to handle this ? 
What are the pros and cons of 3 different files and pipleines method ?

Also, does a property file name should contain all lower case letters ? 
Which one of the following is the best practice?

```
abc.errorcode.mkd-003.useraccount 
abc.errorcode.MKD-003.UserAccount 
abc.errorcode.MKD-003.useraccount
```

Comment: Anyone knows the answer ?